# How to get my images to update and delete

Tags: laravel

I have a page the uploads an image.  It works. But if I want to edit that image to something else and delete the old one, it doesn't work.  Other data updates just not the image.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="brand_image">Update Brand Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="brand_image" id="brand_image" value="{{ $brand->brand_image }}">
  
    @error('brand_image')
        <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
    @enderror
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <img src="{{ asset( 'images/brands/'.$brand->brand_image) }}" width="300" class="mt-2" style="border:1px solid #000;box-shadow: 6px 3px 3px 1px rgba(204, 204, 204, .8);">
 </div>



public function UpdateBrand(Request $request, $id){

        $brand = Brand::find($id);
       $this->validate($request, array(
            'brand_name' => 'required|max:255'
         
                       
       ));

        $brand->brand_name = $request->input('brand_name');
        if($request->hasFile('brand_image')){
            $image = $request->input('brand_image');
            
            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('images/brands/' . $filename);
            Image::make($image)->resize(800,400)->save($location);
            $oldFileName = $brand->brand_name;
        
           unlink($oldFileName);
            
        }
        $brand->save();
        return redirect()->route('all.brands')->with('success','yes');
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the model’s value, I am going to assume your `Brand` model has a `brand_image` attribute so based on the code you showed:

```
if($request->hasFile('brand_image')){
    $image = $request->input('brand_image');
    
    $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location = public_path('images/brands/' . $filename);
    Image::make($image)->resize(800,400)->save($location);


    // this should be the image not the brand name
    $oldFileName = public_path('images/brands/' . $brand->brand_image);
    unlink($oldFileName);

    // finally just update your model’s data
    $brand->brand_image = $filename;
}
```